# Wireless 7265 Wireless adapter not found

Tags: networking, drivers, wireless, dell

I have a Dell Latitude E5450 which I have installed ubuntu 20.04 on and I can't get the wifi adapter to work. I have checked and I do have the recognized wireless 7265 but it is unable to be used for some reason. I have tried moving the intel drivers (iwlwifi7265-14.ucode and iwlwifi7265D-14.ucode) to /lib/firmware. I have attempted lots of searching around and trying various methods but as I'm quite new to linux I am struggling to work out how to implement fixes or work out if they are relevant to my machine. I only have ubuntu 20.04 installed on this device although it previously had windows 10

As requested, here is a pastebin of my wireless info
https://pastebin.ubuntu.com/p/HrGz4WQSdJ/

Comment: See https://askubuntu.com/questions/425155/my-wireless-wifi-connection-does-not-work-what-information-is-needed-to-diagnos/425180

Comment: The output says you are hard blocked. This means there is a hardware switch somewhere on the device or possibly in your BIOS settings that has wifi turned off. It could be a physical switch, it could also be a function or fn key combo on the laptop.

Comment: Other than a wifi switch, it could be an airplane mode switch. At least one website says to press the Fn + PrtScr buttons together for the E5450 model.

Comment: okay awesome I think it was the wifi switch, when I had tried the button combination meant to turn it off before it didn't work but I just went into the BIOS and removed the controls from the switch so now everything is working perfectly. Thank you so much! This has been bugging me for weeks!

Answer (score 1):

Issue was with the wifi switch. Couldn't get the switch to actually work so I just went into BIOS and removed the switches power over my adapters. Now everything seems to be working great.